# React Native: "Unable to resolve module ./App"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

In my React Native app, when I run `react-native bundle --dev false --platform ios --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios` it throws the error `Error: Unable to resolve module ./App from <path to app>/index.js:`. My file at `<path to app>/index.js` is

```
 import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
 import App from './App';
 import {name as appName} from './app.json';
 
 AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

The file `./App` that is causing the error is at `<path to app>/src/App.js`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check path to App.js is correct in Index.js, when you are importing.

Comment: Try to clear metro cache and start metro again, you might be able to see some other error.